# How can one find upper bound over the term, $\int_{0}^{-\lambda\tanh{(x)}}\tanh^{-1}(\frac{v}{\lambda})dv$?

Tags: inequality, indefinite-integrals, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to find an upper bound over the term, 
\begin{equation}
A(x)=\int_{0}^{-\lambda\tanh{(x)}}\tanh^{-1}\Big(\frac{v}{\lambda}\Big)dv
\end{equation}
where $\lambda$ is a constant and $x$ and $v$ are scalars. 
My main aim is to find an expression of the sort, $|A(x)| \leq \kappa$ or $|A(x)| \leq \kappa(x)$.
Please help me find the bound over this quantity!

Comment: I believe $\tanh^{-1}(t)$ has an elementary antiderivative. Is there any reason you don’t just perform the integral and evaluate $A(x)$ explicitly?

Comment: yes I have done that

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicTangent.html

Comment: Yup got it, thanks!